# Enable Sorting and Paging in Gridview Efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, pagination

By using [sample code](http://forums.asp.net/t/956540.aspx/1/10) as a guide, I managed to slap together some code that will perform sorting and paging on a gridview. However, I'm relatively new to webpage programming so I used ViewState quite often (which from what I've gathered, is BAD). As a result, I was wondering if there's anyway to make my code more efficient? (Or different ways of accomplishing the same thing?)

Front end:

```
<asp:GridView ID="UserAccounts" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
    OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize = "20">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Roles" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Roles" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsLockedOut" HeaderText="Locked Out?" SortExpression="IsLockedOut" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsOnline" HeaderText="Online?" SortExpression="IsOnline" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastLoginDate" HeaderText="Last Login Date" SortExpression="LastLoginDate" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Manage" DataNavigateUrlFields="UserName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ManageDetails.aspx?user={0}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind to generate table:

```
private void BindUserAccounts()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("UserName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Email");
        dt.Columns.Add("Roles");
        dt.Columns.Add("IsLockedOut");
        dt.Columns.Add("IsOnline");
        dt.Columns.Add("LastLoginDate");

        var userRoles = from MembershipUser user in Membership.FindUsersByName(this.UsernameToMatch + "%")
                        let roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName)
                        select new
                        {
                            UserName = user.UserName,
                            Email = user.Email,
                            Roles = string.Join(", ", roles),
                            IsLockedOut = user.IsLockedOut,
                            IsOnline = user.IsOnline,
                            LastLoginDate = user.LastLoginDate
                        };

        foreach (var u in userRoles)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["UserName"] = u.UserName;
            dr["Email"] = u.Email;
            dr["Roles"] = u.Roles;
            dr["IsLockedOut"] = u.IsLockedOut;
            dr["IsOnline"] = u.IsOnline;
            dr["LastLoginDate"] = u.LastLoginDate;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        UserAccounts.DataSource = dt;
        UserAccounts.DataBind();
        ViewState["DataSource"] = dt;
}
```

To enable sorting and paging:

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        UserAccounts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindUserAccounts();
    }

    protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)ViewState["DataSource"];

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            if ((string)ViewState["SortDir"] == "ASC" || String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewState["SortDir"]))
            {
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
                ViewState["SortDir"] = "DESC";
            }
            else if ((string)ViewState["SortDir"] == "DESC")
            {
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
                ViewState["SortDir"] = "ASC";
            }

            UserAccounts.DataSource = dataView;
            UserAccounts.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keeping the value of your sorting direction in ViewState is fine.  What you need to look at is just returning & binding the records for the page you are on.

Comment: As I can remember, you don't need that foreach block of code. You just need to set datasource to that user roles query. This could speedup sorting and comparing values, you just need to apply right linq extensions to query. This would work since you have already specified column names in select part of query.

Comment: Don't add the whole `DataTable` into ViewState. It increases the size of your page and reduces the performance, also ViewState can be deciphered on the client side, so the DataTable is not secure. Use Session or -even better - don't persist it at all since you're GridView is using ViewState by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is as efficient as it can be due to the way that you are binding the data to the GridView. More efficient ways can be achieved but not without changing the data binding logic.

For example, a more efficient way to do this could be to handle paging and sorting on the client side using jQuery+[dataTables](http://datatables.net). Another way that would require less code from your part can be accomplished using `SqlDataSource` and setting it as the `DataSource` for the GridView - you wouldn't have to do the resorting/paging in code. But again, both approaches require significant changes. Your code is as efficient as it can be IMO.

**Update:**
Tim made a good point on his comment - don't persist the data table on ViewState. Either put it in Session (consider the size of the data before starting to put things in Session) or simply ask the DB to send the data again. Adding this DataTable to ViewState will considerably increase the page size.

Comment: Okay, I managed to remove viewstate by replacing that line with               BindUserAccounts();
            DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)UserAccounts.DataSource; within gridview_sorting. However I must ask, is it worthwhile to look into using SQLDATASOURCE for this application?

Comment: @Tony but do you still have `ViewState["DataSource"] = dt;` line in `BindUserAccounts`? If so, remove it as well. That line still adds the DT to `ViewState`. You need to put it on Session or call the DB again instead. For example: In the last line of BindUserAccounts do: `Session["DataSource"] = dt;` and then you can retrieve it on GridViewSorting by doing:  `DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)Session["DataSource"];`

Comment: Yes i've removed that as well, Thanks. Viewstate is only being used for asc/desc row sort.

Answer (score 0):

good tips given you provided to see what to use what is not. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I also personally believe that session is more light and secure than viewstate. i found one more simple example at this site http://blogfornet.com/2013/09/gridview-paging-and-sorting-example/. It will help beginner to understand.