# The data source does not support server-side data paging when sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I'm trying to make my gridview sortable. I have allow sorting and added a onsorting attribute given below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="detail, propertydetail,suspectdetail " BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GWCase_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" CurrentSortField="memberreportid" CurrentSortDirection="ASC">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />

<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="memberreportid" HeaderText="MemberReportID" SortExpression="memberreportid"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="typeofcrime" HeaderText="Type of Crime" SortExpression="typeofcrime" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="crdatetime" HeaderText="ReportDateTime" SortExpression="crdatetime" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="address" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="incidentdate" HeaderText="Incident Date" SortExpression="incidentdate" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="incidenttime" HeaderText="Incident Time" SortExpression="incidenttime"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="property" HeaderText="Property" SortExpression="Property"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="victim" HeaderText="Victim" SortExpression="victim" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="suspect" HeaderText="Suspect" SortExpression="suspect"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="detail" HeaderText="Detail" SortExpression="detail" Visible="false"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my c# code i used to enable the sorting

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        string sortField = string.Empty;

        SortGridview((GridView)sender, e, out sortDirection, out sortField);

        string strSortDirection = e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        //Error happens here
        GWCase.DataSource = (e.SortExpression + " " + strSortDirection);
        GWCase.DataBind();
    }


    private void SortGridview(GridView gridView, GridViewSortEventArgs e, out SortDirection sortDirection, out string sortField)
    {
        sortField = e.SortExpression;
        sortDirection = e.SortDirection;

        if (gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] != null && gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] != null)
        {
            if (sortField == gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortField"])
            {
                if (gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] == "ASC")
                {
                    sortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                }
            }

            gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] = sortField;
            gridView.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] = (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
        }
    }
```

The tutorial i follow required a data layer which i didnt use as i have binded my gridview with boundfield. However when trying to get my datasource they gave me the error stated above.

This is how i bind my gridview

```
private void LoadGrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI";
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT memberreportid, typeofcrime, crdatetime, address, detail, incidentdate, incidenttime, property, victim, suspect, detail, suspectdetail, propertydetail from memberreport where assignto = 'unassign'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        GWCase.DataSource = ds.Copy();
        GWCase.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code where you are originally binding the `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following line of code:

```
GWCase.DataSource = (e.SortExpression + " " + strSortDirection);
```

This is telling the `GridView` to bind to something that is not the same type of data source you originally bound the grid to. For example, if the user had selected to sort by clicking the `Victim` column, then the above code would try to set a string of `victim ascending` as the data source, which clearly is incorrect.

To get quick paging/sorting capabilities into a `GridView` the easiest way is to use the `DataTable` data structure, along with a `DataView` data structure.

A previous StackOverflow question details an example of doing this. The question itself details the usage of `DataTable` and `DataView` to facilitate the sorting and paging, along with using `ViewState` to maintain whether the sorting direction is ascending or descending.

Read [Enable Sorting and Paging in Gridview Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571710/enable-sorting-and-paging-in-gridview-efficiently) to see the code example.

To more appropriately handle paging/sorting, you would want to incorporate custom paging and sorting instead of the `AllowPaging=True` and `AllowSorting=True` settings on the `GridView`. The reason for this is that those `GridView` settings still ask for all of the rows from whatever data source you are using (usually a database) and loads it all into memory, which if it is 20 rows that is not so bad, but imagine 10,000 rows of data; it will be slow and inefficient use of memory. True paging will only get the exact amount of rows to show on the page and then ask for another page chunk when the user navigates; it is more chatty with calling the database more than once, but it is extremely fast and efficient memory-wise.

Comment: The OP should have given you a +1 for this effort mate! It saved me time, especially when you mentioned "The reason for this is that those GridView settings still ask for all of the rows from whatever data source you are using (usually a database) and loads it all into memory,"

Comment: @Fernando68 glad it helped you